Similar TV show as MANHUNT on Discovery channel?
One or two years ago there was a TV show about 5-6 people (experts in various fields) which have the task to find one person in the USA. All they have is usually a photo, a video or something like that. It was aired on Discovery or NatGeo.
Does somebody know what the name of that show is?

Welcome to [movies.se]. I removed the second and off-topic part about a recommendation list for now. For that, take a look here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9301/49.

Can you clarify - do you mean this show was on tv within the last two years, or was it released more than two years ago.

@NapoleonWilson Great, I agree with you. Thanks!

@AndrewMartin I'm not sure. I watched it before year or two. Its highly possible that it was released before that.

Perhaps 'Off The Grid' from late 2011? From an online recap:

Armed with only very basic information about the two contestants, a team of surveillance experts led by human tracking expert Kevin Reeve, is tasked with learning enough about the contestants to find where they might be and then to go out and actually bring them in.

However, this was on the History Channel and I think it was a one-off. You can see the trailer on Youtube, as well as the entire episode.
[Other vague possibilities: NatGeo's The Great American Manhunt (AKA Mystery Manhunt), but that's about a team of experts locating someone using forensic clues; and there's Discovery's Mantracker, but there's mainly one tracker there.]

Its the The Great American Manhunt! Thanks a lot!!!
