# How to find films that contain a specific motif?

Tags: reference

I suspect that the question I have is off topic for this site. I'm looking for **movies about terrorist acts told from the terrorists' viewpoint**. It does not matter whether the films are about "good" terrorism (i.e. revolutionaries trying to force an oppressive government to do good things) or "bad" terrorism (i.e. terrorists fighting against commonly held values and ideals), as that distinction will depend on who's side one is on and is not one relevant to the narrative structure I'm after.

As the question itself will most likely be off topic, I'd like to ask **how I can find such movies** and what methods and strategies I can employ to find them.

There is no list of such movies (that I could find) similar to Wikipedia lists of genre movies (e.g. [List of thriller films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_thriller_films)) and a Google search for "[films from terrorist viewpoint](https://www.google.com/search?q=films%20from%20terrorist%20viewpoint%20OR%20perspective)" only turned up a handful of examples in [a Reddit list](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/2qs0bh/are_there_any_good_movies_from_the_terrorist/). Maybe it is not a viewpoint that many movies take on, but maybe I'm just searching the wrong way.

So, more generally maybe, how does someone go about finding movies with a specific motif?

*(I'm not sure about the proper tags for this question, so please edit, if you know.)*

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or **resources to locate** or watch movie/TV content are off topic

Comment: @Paulie_D I am asking for "methods and strategies", not resources. The title of my question asks "how", not "where".

Comment: Same thing....that's not something we do here on the main site. You could try [chat].

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9301/how-can-i-find-tv-shows-films-similar-to-one-i-like

Comment: @user58980 I agree that the question is off topic but regardless, are you looking for serious movie or action ones like V for Vendetta, Swordfish, fight club, or a drama like Homeland, Mr Robot, The east?

Comment: @madmada Both serious and action. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I was going to suggest using IMDB's "Keywords" feature, using Four Lions as an example, but unfortunately [it didn't have any suitable keyword](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1341167/keywords?ref_=tt_stry_kw)s :-/ You might have better luck starting with a different film!

Comment: Thank you, @user568458, that's a great idea, but I seem unable to find a "viewpoint" keyword or something similar on IMDB. From the keywords on IMDB (e.g. "murder") it is unclear what viewpoint a movie is told from (e.g. murderer or victim or sleuth).

Comment: Yeah I was hoping for, say, "anti-hero", reasoning that films with both the "terrorism" and "anti-hero" keywords would probably have a terrorist protagonist. But Four Lions had neither keyword... so it's clearly not reliable

Comment: May be try some creativity with the keywords, instead of "terrorists" try "freedom fighters" may be "resistance" "anti government" etc.

Comment: From experience, [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/) has the largest manually maintained categorization of movies/TV shows based on recurring narrative devices. (1) Think of a movie that fits your description (2) Look up the movie on TV tropes (3) Read its tropes, and find the trope that describes your motif (4) Click through to the trope's page, which contains a list of works that implement this trope (and a short description to explain why it does).

Comment: Maybe this could get a community wiki answer? i feel it could also help people to find movies they are looking for before they ask identify-this-movie questions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about search engine techniques and not a good fit for the site. Perhaps Super User is a better site.